# store data in the client after devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

in my rails app, after successfully logging in with devise, I want to call an external service which returns a token. How can I pass it to the client in order it to be persisted (for example in localStorage)?

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
    login_to_chat #successful login
  end

  def login_to_chat
    uri = URI('https://xxxxxx.ws/authenticate')

    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.body = params[:user].slice(:username,:password).to_json

    res = https.request(req)

    if res.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
      json = JSON.parse(res.body)

      # how can I pass json['public_token'] to the client?

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which solution will be the best fit in your context. My idea is:

1. Write the token to cookie in the controller (which user can access easily)

   ```
   cookies[key] = value
   ```
2. This is the 'create' method in Devise::SessionsController

   ```
   def create
     self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
     set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
     sign_in(resource_name, resource)
     yield resource if block_given?
     respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   end
   ```

   So you can overwrite the 'after_sign_in_path_for' method with your token as parameter, client know that parameter and you can do whatever you want
3. In case, the 'login_to_chat' takes a long time, we can do it in background then notify client via websocket

Comment: tnx hieu. Even if I didn't specify this is what I needed: multiple options to better evaluate security concerns.